# Using a struct variable inside a class constructor

Tags: c++, class, struct

```
struct Date
{
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
};

class Person
{
private:
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    Date dOB;
public:
    Person();
    Person(const string& f, const string& l, const Date& d);
};

Person::Person() : firstName("None"), lastName("None"), dOB(dOB.day(0),dOB.month(0), dOB.year(0)) {}
```

I have a Struct Date with 3 variables day, month, year.
Below, in the class Person, I am using Date for the constructor. But when I set the day, month and year = 0 it shows error that I have that expression must have pointer-to function type? What is my problem here? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler thinks the syntax `dOB.day(0)` is a function call.

Instead of naming the members, you can write it like this:

```
Person::Person() : firstName("None"), lastName("None"), dOB{0,0,0} {}
```

where each member of `dOB` gets initialized to 0.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/q-YoxP).

Answer (score 1):

Add a CTOR to your `Date` struct:

```
Date(int day, int month, int year) : year(year), month(month), day(day) {}
```

Use it:

```
Person::Person() : firstName("None"), lastName("None"), dOB(0, 0, 0) {}
```

Or:

```
Person::Person(const string& f, const string& l, const Date& d) : dOB(d) { /*...*/ };
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Date` struct is `Aggregate type` - read for [Aggregate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

you can use either `direct initialization` or `list initialization`

```
Person::Person() : firstName("None"), lastName("None"), dOB(0, 0, 0) {} // direct initialization


Person::Person() : firstName("None"), lastName("None"), dOB{0, 0, 0} {} // list initialization
```

Answer (score 0):

Aboves already included two ways of intializing your `dOB` struct.

However if you only want a default ctor for your `Person` class, you don't even need to init `dOB` yourself, as `int` would be auto init to `0`, and `dOb` would be auto initialized to `{0, 0, 0}`